# Как создать форму с отдельным потоком для обработки виндоус сообщений?

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность, vb.net

Для программы создаётся расширение на .NET с использованием WinForms. Из этого расширение вызывается форма.

Проблема в том, что поток с виндоус очередью у основного приложения повисает. Как сделать, так чтобы у формы расширения был отдельный поток на обработку очереди сообщений?
И как его правильно потом остановить после отключения расширения?

**UPD**

Утрированный пример:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.Show();

    Thread.Sleep(1000 * 10); // что-то долго делает.

    form2.Close();
}
```

Здесь требуется чтобы форма `form2` нормально прорисовывалась и реагировала на действия пользователя, хотя при этом поток родительской формы виснет на обработке чего-нибудь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы `form2` работала в отдельном потоке независимо от родительской окна можно создать поток и установить у него апартаменты `STA`. Из этом потока показываем `form2`.

Основываясь на [этом примере](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21684059/1133809) создаем класс второго потока:
(**UPD** по совету @PavelMayorov упрощаем реализацию)

```
class SecondWindowsThread : IDisposable
{
    private SynchronizationContext ctx;

    public SecondWindowsThread()
    {
        ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        try
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(
                () =>
                {
                    this.ctx = new WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext();
                    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(this.ctx);
                    mre.Set();
                    Application.Run();
                }
            );
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();
            mre.WaitOne();
        }
        finally
        {
            mre.Dispose();
        }
    }

    #region IDisposable Support
    private bool disposedValue = false;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (disposedValue) return;

        if (this.ctx != null)
        {
            this.ctx.Send((_) => Application.ExitThread(), null);
            this.ctx = null;
        }
        disposedValue = true;
    }

    #endregion

    public SynchronizationContext SynchronizationContext
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.disposedValue) throw new ObjectDisposedException(nameof(SynchronizationContext));
            return this.ctx;
        }
    }
}
```

Тогда обработчик кнопки будет такой:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = null;

    using (var t2 = new SecondWindowsThread())
    {
        t2.SynchronizationContext.Send(
            (_) =>
            {
                form2 = new Form2();
                form2.Show();
            }, null);

        Thread.Sleep(1000 * 10); // что-то долго делает.

        t2.SynchronizationContext.Send((_) => form2.Close(), null);
    }
}
```

При этом надо учитывать, что работать с компонентами одной формы из другой надо через синхронизирующий контекст или методы [Control.Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zyzhdc6b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [Control.BeginInvoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke(v=vs.110).aspx).

[Лабораторная работа](https://github.com/maliutin/lab-Window-in-another-WM-thread)

[image]

Comment: Вместо того чтобы дергать `Application.Idle` туда-сюда, стоило бы создать и установить `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` самостоятельно...

Comment: @PavelMayorov не понятна идея. Особенно в контексте того, что надо делать с `mre`. Где тогда вызывать `mre.Set()`? Я подготовил [проект](https://github.com/maliutin/Window-in-another-windows-thread). Можете уточнить?

Comment: Вот как контекст в переменную запишите - так и `mre.Set()`. А какие еще варианты-то?

Comment: @PavelMayorov т.е. перед `Application.Run()`. Тогда вопрос, в этом случае не надо гарантировать, что вызов `Application.Run()` будет до `t2.SynchronizationContext.Send`? Или `thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)` уже это обеспечивает?

Comment: Нет, не надо. Это обеспечивает тот факт, что вы создаете контекст самостоятельно.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Понятно. Обновил. Спасибо.

Comment: Кажется, вы забыли [установить контекст](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.setsynchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx)...

Comment: @PavelMayorov А это `this.ctx = new WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext()`? Так надо?

Comment: А это - создание контекста. После создания его надо установить.

Comment: Т.е. установить для текущего второго потока. Поправил. Так?

Comment: Да, так........