# Открыть форму в приостановленной консоли

Tags: c#, winforms, консоль

Есть такой код:

```
class Program
{
    static EasyGetUni unificator = new EasyGetUni(); 
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ////Вход
        Console.WriteLine("LogingIn");
        unificator.Login();
        ////Вход
        //
        /////Рабочая часть

        Task open = new Task(()=> new Program().startwindow());
        open.Start();


        /////Рабочая часть
        //
        ////Выход
        ///

        Console.WriteLine("LogingOut");
        unificator.Logout();
        Console.WriteLine("Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу...");
        Console.ReadKey();
        ////Выход
    }
    void startwindow()
    {
        MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
        main.Show();
    }
}
```

Проблема: Зависает окно во время запуска, и не загружает его дальше пары объектов. А код доходит до Readline-a и при закрытии консоли - закрывается все. Как можно это все реализовать?

Comment: Вообще-то в шаблоне проекта для WinForms всё есть. Используйте его.

Comment: Вопрос все же состоит в том как пользоваться формой пока ждет консоль, если это невозможно, то так и скажите.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277771/how-to-run-a-winform-from-console-application

Comment: Вам нужно создать отдельный STA поток и открыть там форму. [Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/858212/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9/868100#868100) пример на русском.